# bin-packaging layout with similar to masonry.js or isotope.js without ordering by existing elements

Tags: javascript, bin-packing

I trying to create layout that will be filled with elements in way of minimizing whitespace between them. The problem is that all libraries I tried do this ordering items from left to right and from top to bottom the way they get defined. Here is some example:

```
<div id="layout_wrapper">
<div class="item">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

This items will fill layout_wrapper from left to right and top to bottom beginning with 1 and finishing with 4. But this way there may be gaps that must be filled with other, suitable item - lets say 1, 4, 3, 2 - will be optimal way of filling layout.

But I cant make this work. I know that this is handful for situations like dynamic content loading when content must be placed the way it gets, but in my case I need an other behaviour.

So, does anybody know how to make this work in masonry.js or any other similar library making bin packing algorithm to work the way I need? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

2d bin-packing is very difficult you can try a kd-tree and recursively subdivide the tree (http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/lightmaps/default.html). Or there is the perfect masonry (http://www.drewdahlman.com/meusLabs/?p=218). I have never tried it but it seems to be an exact solver.